# Enabling TCP/IPv4 through Windows PE

Tags: windows, tcpip

From RDP, i've disabled the TCP/IPv4 protocol by mistake and now, obviously, i can't use rdp anymore to re-enable it. Is there a way to enable it again from Windows PE?(OVH rescue pro)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use your out of band management card for this, (ILO, DRAC, BMC, OVH vKVM etc.,) or the virtual console on the hypervisor if this is a virtual machine. You'll have to log in using either cached domain credentials or a local account. Or, just F8 the thing during boot and restore a previous system state or last known good configuration.

If you don't have a OOB management solution in this computer, then you can

- Get in your car, drive to the datacenter and log on to the console of the machine.
- Call your datacenter to go do it for you ("remote hands" - costs money.)

Comment: It's a dedicated server with windows 2008 server. I can reboot through ovh panel choosing netboot rescue-pro, which is basically WinPE.

Comment: How do i swap it to WinRE? The only available modes in ovh are rescue-pro(which a unix web-thing for test only and ssh access), and winpe.

Comment: @user188237 Use OVH's vKVM mode to get access to the console. You can then boot Windows normally and make the necessary changes.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you... I'll add that to my list of "OOB management solutions."  :)